# Error with " Not an S3 object with class gg/ggplot"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am getting the following error:

> Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by
> `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class gg/ggplot

And this is my code, which works perfectly with a different dataset:

```
household_income <- ggplot(household_income, aes(nationality, avg_income))
household_income + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(nationality))) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', 
               stackdir='center',
               binwidth = 1,
               dotsize = .45, 
               fill="red") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=0, vjust=.9))
```

I am essentially trying to replicate the Box_Dot plot [here](http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html#Dot%20+%20Box%20Plot)

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of the data?

Comment: Based on the error message, it's likely because you've assigned your dataset's name (`household_income`) to your ggplot object, overwriting it. Try naming the ggplot object something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the pipe (`%>%`) used often in `dplyr` to pass the data to `ggplot`

Making an example data.frame:

```
household_income = data.frame(
   nationality =sample(1:5,100,replace=TRUE),
   avg_income = rnbinom(100,mu=50,size=1)
)
```

Don't know your data.frame (so please provide it to make it a minimum reproducible example), for the `geom_dotplot()` and `boxplot()` to overlay, nationality has to be a factor. I used `mutate()` to factorize it on the fly below. And you set a lower alpha on the boxplot to see the dots:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

household_income %>% 
mutate(nationality=factor(nationality)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(nationality, avg_income))+ 
geom_boxplot(aes(fill=nationality),alpha=0.1) + 
geom_dotplot(binaxis='y',stackdir='center',dotsize=0.45,fill='red') + 
theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, as you can see in your graph it is not really reflecting the code.. any idea how? For instance, the the dotsize is not the same and the dots are not colored in red.

Comment: ok i see now.. you are trying to overlay a boxplot with a scatter plot. is this the plot you wanted? geom_dotplot() works in a different way.. You can try to use geom_point() instead

Comment: Correct, as in the link here:

http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html#Dot%20+%20Box%20Plot

The Box+Dot plot